# Save String variables in a JSON file in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have 3 variables:

```
String Phone, Password and Location;
```

that I want to save in json file as:

```
phone:"xxxxx",password:"yyyyyy',location:"zzzzz"
```

The above JSON is not correct and I have put it only to show what I need.

I don't want to add extra class in project just to save 3 variables in a JSON file.

My preferred library is Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=FoOfUQswuE5Bw5yHJFHo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can serialize an anonymous type like this.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
   password = Password,
   phone = Phone,
   location = Location
});
```

Edited to fix object init syntax.

Additionally as shown in Zohars almost identical answer. If you just use the variable name, then the property is automatically created with the same name.

Comment: Now my rep is over 125 so your answer has an upvote from me @ZoharPeled, since it compiled and you included a live demo

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize an anonymous type:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Phone, Password, Location});
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/QIGKL73388)